# How to surround words with quotes

Tags: c#, regex

How to surround words with quotes
Ex.
United states, US, with 'United states', 'US',

Comment: Define "word". "United States" appears to be two words to me.

Comment: I have string like in ex. 
String s = "United States, US" 
replace this string With string s1 = " 'United states', 'US'"

Comment: Do you intend to surround with quotes parts of string between `,`? The sample you have provided is vague, it's obviously what `United states` is not a "word"

Comment: Ok, let me try to be as simple as possible.
I have a list of countries and their country codes, i want to surround line(or word, call it whatever you want ) with single quotes
example line United State, US, should look like this 
'United States', 'US',
I hope things are more clear now.

Comment: @Michael: Can there be more than one comma? If so, is it always the last comma in the string that delimits the first and second parts?

Comment: I can remove the commas from such words as BOLIVIA, PLURINATIONAL STATE OF so it can be BOLIVIA PLURINATIONAL STATE OF and then that string can be transformed into what i want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case

```
resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, @"\b[^,]+\b", "'$0'");
```

would work, but you might want to define your requirements a little more clearly.

EDIT:

Now that you've clarified that your string is always divided into two parts (Name and Country Code), this might be better:

```
resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, @"^(.+),\s*([^,]+)$", "'$1', '$2'", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

This will change the multiline string

```
United States, US
Switzerland, CH
BOLIVIA, PLURINATIONAL STATE OF, BO
```

into

```
'United States', 'US'
'Switzerland', 'CH'
'BOLIVIA, PLURINATIONAL STATE OF', 'BO'
```

(but also works if you apply it to one line at a time).

Comment: This will break e.g. with "Nation of Brunei, the Abode of Peace,BR" - note that this is the official name: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brunei . Also, various other gotchas like "Denmark, Kingdom of, DK". As you state, the requirements are unclear.

Comment: Your regex yields rersult - `'United States''', 'US'''`. I think you should replace `*` with `+`

Comment: @Piskvor
I got country names from 
http://www.iso.org/iso/english_country_names_and_code_elements

Comment: @Anton: I don't see this behaviour in RegexBuddy, but this is a good idea nonetheless.

Comment: @Michael27: See the first page, then: `BOLIVIA, PLURINATIONAL STATE OF,  BO ;
BONAIRE, SAINT EUSTATIUS AND SABA,  BQ` - the extra commas will break the regex

Comment: @Piskvor: you are right, but OP didnt ask about such situations. This codes also avaliable as txt file http://www.iso.org/iso/list-en1-semic-3.txt and such format has different delimiters

Comment: @Anton Semenov: True - I have noted this in my first comment.

Comment: +1 for a solution that works on strings other than the posted example.

Answer (score 3):

```
var quoted = myString.Replace("US", "'US'").Replace("United States", "'United States'");
```

No need for regex for a simple task.

Comment: Actually regex is required because i have a List of string from txt file

Comment: If this list of string is List<string>, then use foreach in combination with StringBuilder class. You'll have way better performance than regex.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple solution, using string manipulation:

```
string s = "BOLIVIA, PLURINATIONAL STATE OF, BO";
```

Wrap with single quotes:

```
int lastComma = s.LastIndexOf(", ");
s = String.Format("'{0}', '{1}'", s.Remove(lastComma), s.Substring(lastComma + 2));
```

If you always have 2 letters at the end of the string, you can simplify it even further:

```
int lastComma = s.Length - 4;
```

You probably want some error checking, but this looks like a very simple task, that doesn't require anything as fancy as a regular expression.